# Fresh Install of Ubuntu Server 19.04 Has No Internet?

Tags: networking, server, internet, 19.04

I just finished installing the new Ubuntu 19.04 Server on my downstairs server, but it doesn't appear to have an internet connection despite being wired to the router using a cat-6 cable.

All pings fail, including `ping 8.8.8.8` with the same error message. I've tried using `ifconfig` to set the state to `up`, but this didn't help.

`ip a` reveals that the server doesn't seem to have an IP address.

Pictures below:
[image: Ubuntu Server]

Comment: Did you tried to use `sudo dhclient enp0s25`? Just curious why do you use 9 month-supported Ubuntu on server instead of LTS with 5 years of support?

Comment: It could be a DHCP issue, but I would honestly start bare bones here and check the back of the server for a link light. It should be gree, not amber. Let us know what you find.

Comment: @N0rbert This is just for my backup server. I didn't really care although I probably should have used the LTS release. I'm not doing anything serious. It just has to stay functional for a month while I'm gone for backups. I guess I'll replace it with 18.04LTS since that has been debugged better.

Comment: @N0rbert Your solution fixed the issue. It now has an IP address. I don't know why it didn't set up that way though. I'm not really knowledgeable about networking yet. If you post your solution as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it :]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To obtain IP address from DHCP server manually you can run

```
sudo dhclient enp0s25
```

To make this solution permanent you should use the corresponding configuration file inside 19.04 for Netplan (see [server guide, p. 43](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/serverguide.pdf)) - `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` with the following contents:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: yes
```

then apply the configuration with `sudo netplan apply`.

The file contents of `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` above is modified variant of `/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/dhcp.yaml` configuration file.
More examples of Netplan configuration are shown in `/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/`.

Comment: The first part of your answer got my internet working. Thanks, but in 19.10 it seems that /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml becomes /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml. However, the configuration you have provided doesn't work. I keep getting an "inconsistent indentation" error no matter how I move the indentations around. Do I need to add more info maybe?

Comment: @i9pp0 I'm not sure about CloudInit, see https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config.html